# Calling a shared method produces a weird array out of bounds error

Tags: typescript, runtime-error, motoko, internet-computer

A TypeScript client does not work for DFINITY Motoko:

```js
function initializeDirectCanDBPartitionClient(canisterId: Principal)
{
  const host = isLocal ? "http://127.0.0.1:8000" : "https://ic0.app";
  const agent = new HttpAgent({ host });
  return Actor.createActor(CanDBPartitionIDL, { agent, canisterId });
};
...
const client = initializeDirectCanDBPartitionClient(obj.itemRef.canister);
obj.item = await client.getItem(BigInt(obj.itemRef.id)) as any;
```

produces

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Call failed:
  Canister: a3shf-5eaaa-aaaaa-qaafa-cai
  Method: getItem (query)
  "Status": "rejected"
  "Code": "CanisterError"
  "Message": "IC0503: Canister a3shf-5eaaa-aaaaa-qaafa-cai trapped explicitly: Array index out of bounds"
    at caller (index.js:184:27)
    at async ItemData.create (index.js:78705:20)
```

But

```
  public query func getItem(itemId: Nat): async ?lib.Item {
    Debug.print("ITEMXXX");
    return null; // to ensure the action is completely done
    let data = _getAttribute({sk = "i/" # Nat.toText(itemId)}, "i");
    Debug.print("ITEM: " # debug_show(data));
    do ? { lib.deserializeItem(data!) };
  };
```

should output at least `ITEMXXX`, which however does not appear in the logs of `dfx start`.

Why the error?!

Comment: Note that the debugger shows `isLocal === true`.

Comment: It seems, that it is explainable by canister ID being missing in `.env` file, what is in turn explainable by a canister missing in `dfx.json` dependencies of the canister that was last deployed.